# How do I login with Google OAuth Through a Desktop App?

Tags: c#, winforms, oauth-2.0, google-oauth, winui-3

Currently I am building a desktop app using WinUI3 and C#.
I have noticed other apps that do this but I can't figure out how they are doing it.
Example would be a button that says "Login with Google" on the desktop app.
Clicking that button opens a webpage in their default browser to then allow them to login with their Google account.
I do know how to build Google login into a website, so I am assuming I just make that oauth call at the URL I send them too, then say they can close the browser when they login.
Where I got lost is how does the desktop app then know who is logged in?

Comment: Google has samples here: https://github.com/googlesamples/oauth-apps-for-windows